# Open specific tab with <a href> and save to localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a table whose current value is stored in `localStorage` (see [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/628m04wr/28/)). How do I set up a link in `<a href>` to open the desired table, e.g. second in order?

For example: I'm on the Home page and clicking `<a href>` redirects me to the List page, where tab Teacher is opened, and this option is also saved to `localStorage` (that is, when the List page is refreshed, the Teacher tab remains open).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a link to an HTML page, which, on that page, there are various options for a current tab to be selected, and you want, that when someone clicks on a particular link, that tab will already be open.

Am I right?

If so, then let's do the following.

If you're setting the value when the page loads based on `localStorage`, then by definition it will only open that which was opened last.

So the question is how do you make the particular link open only one tab, and another link open the other? It seems from your example that you want a link to the "student" tab and a separate link to the "teacher" tab.

To do this just with client side JavaScript, you can use the window location [hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp), and read it with JavaScript, and do the respective function based on the hash value.

Say you have some URL like [example.com](https://google.com), which brings you to a default tab. Then, if you want a link to a non default tab, simply add something to the end of the URL preceded by a "#" symbol, then you can read it in JavaScript with `location.hash`

So the new URL may look like: [example.com/#teacher](https://google.com), then somewhere in your page with JavaScript, do:

```
var page = location.hash //== "#teacher"
    activateTab(page.replace("#", "")); //activates "teacher" tab, assuming that function would do something, but you get the idea
```